# How do you find the size of a bucket in riak? (in MB and ignoring the backups)

Tags: node.js, riak

I am building a node.js application using riak as the data storage solution.
The application will allow for some data storage from users. I want some way to track how much space is being used by a single user (1 user -> x buckets). I also want to ignore the distributed copies (only count 1 copy).

I have not been able to find anything to calculate the approximate space used. Using a node.js script is fine, though I would prefer a way to do it in the database (in a distributed fashion)

Does anyone have an idea of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in previous posts there is 2 ways of doing this:

1. Doing a post commit hooks is the best option, if  you implement it in a map/reduce job you can use byte_size on the content of the object (see below)
2. Implement a map/reduce job, check out https://github.com/whitenode/riak_mapreduce_utils and their `map_datasize` function

**erlang commit hook**

```
update_bucket_size_hook(Object) ->
my_hooks_utils:update_bucket_size(riakc_obj:key(Object), 
  erlang:byte_size(riak_object:get_value(Object))).
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a Riak noob, but based on what I know my first instinct would be to look at a Post-Commit hook, where you have access to the object and properties - including size, I believe. You could then adjust the values in a separate bucket that tracks usage. Not sure if pre- or post-commit hooks are constrained to operations on the object that triggered the hook, though. Maybe in the post-commit hook could add a secondary index to the object in question with the size of the file, which you could access via MapReduce in the future.

I apologize if maybe I'm thinking out loud...it seems like an interesting problem so I'm interested to see how you solve it. I've been meaning to play with the hooks myself but haven't had a chance.

[Commit Hooks](http://wiki.basho.com/Commit-Hooks.html)

Comment: Ok, ill take a look at the hooks. I was considering map-reduce and did not notice any size access.

Answer (score 0):

The current total size of the data in a bucket (or for an arbitrary set of records) can be retrieved through a mapreduce query. This will provide the size irrespective of where the records are stored and the number of copies kept. As I was not able to find any mapreduce function that actually returns the size of the data, I created one. This is called **map_datasize** and can be found [in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/whitenode/riak_mapreduce_utils).

Running this mapreduce query on the contents of an entire bucket will likely be quite slow and put some load on the system (running mapreduce jobs on entire buckets is not recommended), but could perhaps be used if the size only need to be determined occasionally.

If you always require an up to date figure, I think a post-commit hook, as suggested in the other post, might be a better option, although it may be a bit tricky to keep it accurate as I am not sure whether you would have access to the size of the record being replaced on updates in order to calculate the change in size.